# Set the Background of a DataGridRow based on the content of a cell

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

Is there a way, using XAML, to dynamically set the background of a row based on the content of one of it's cells?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define a style for a row and change the color using DataTrigger. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BooleanPropertyOnObjectBoundToRow}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Here `BooleanPropertyOnObjectBoundToRow` is a boolean property on your data object one the cells is bound to.

Comment: How do I make the color dynamic instead of just Red?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've misunderstood. My property is actually an `Enum` I guess I can make an enum to boolean converter for the binding.

Comment: @Phil: You also can specify your own enumeration values for the Value-proeprty of the Binding. For this you must declare the namespace of your enumeration and the set it in the value attribute with Value="{x:Static yourNamespace:YourEnum.YourValue}"

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured that out alone.

Comment: Not sure I understand this: Binding="{Binding BooleanPropertyOnObjectBoundToRow}" what is this?